# Make openssl list root CA certificate

Tags: tls, certificates, openssl, certificate-authority, x.509

I want openssl to list entire cert chain, including root CA, when executing:

`openssl s_client -showcerts -connect host:443`

However, this is not the case. Depth 2 cert root CA cert is not included:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect www.google.com:443
CONNECTED(00000005)
depth=2 OU = GlobalSign Root CA - R2, O = GlobalSign, CN = GlobalSign
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = Google Trust Services, CN = GTS CA 1O1
verify return:1
depth=0 C = US, ST = California, L = Mountain View, O = Google LLC, CN = www.google.com
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=US/ST=California/L=Mountain View/O=Google LLC/CN=www.google.com
   i:/C=US/O=Google Trust Services/CN=GTS CA 1O1
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIFkzCCBHugAwIBAgIQP1H8lc2ARYwDAAAAALrahTANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBC
MQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzEeMBwGA1UEChMVR29vZ2xlIFRydXN0IFNlcnZpY2VzMRMw
EQYDVQQDEwpHVFMgQ0EgMU8xMB4XDTIwMTExMDE0MjgwOVoXDTIxMDIwMjE0Mjgw
OFowaDELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxEzARBgNVBAgTCkNhbGlmb3JuaWExFjAUBgNVBAcT
DU1vdW50YWluIFZpZXcxEzARBgNVBAoTCkdvb2dsZSBMTEMxFzAVBgNVBAMTDnd3
dy5nb29nbGUuY29tMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAvnPJ
VeaTK7pGoNtG1rGNLHR2y2aYUXJx5+mHCUQsn0+hsEb1VXJQtbI61Zs8HEH3kGmd
PD3opQoH5wY9uBadLMsGXtfSeuFCIJThLgz8SCTOr7Q/BDJqZ37HaibQfYu8upcR
Mvd/Gp5udJAy2uFlQ5o5vCf0ySAPXrN1fmhh1z6pIXJa0pLmG/rysSMAJZbVOF0J
nEfJ1/HTGiPzzNON37DHvWc1t13tFuc3xiIsWQrEkOoknhLAiZvle0R9CNB2vawd
aQmRXLHRi+1BJRLvgCDgdM/wMdLwDUHCPf08B3WC7O2W3yxu8Tu3AWC7g1LY0XRb
24qAW+8e7VzPmfRvBQIDAQABo4ICXTCCAlkwDgYDVR0PAQH/BAQDAgWgMBMGA1Ud
JQQMMAoGCCsGAQUFBwMBMAwGA1UdEwEB/wQCMAAwHQYDVR0OBBYEFBvBctGy1itS
cOPrDhxR3cCF31OaMB8GA1UdIwQYMBaAFJjR+G4Q68+b7GCfGJAboOt9Cf0rMGgG
CCsGAQUFBwEBBFwwWjArBggrBgEFBQcwAYYfaHR0cDovL29jc3AucGtpLmdvb2cv
Z3RzMW8xY29yZTArBggrBgEFBQcwAoYfaHR0cDovL3BraS5nb29nL2dzcjIvR1RT
MU8xLmNydDAZBgNVHREEEjAQgg53d3cuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbTAhBgNVHSAEGjAYMAgG
BmeBDAECAjAMBgorBgEEAdZ5AgUDMDMGA1UdHwQsMCowKKAmoCSGImh0dHA6Ly9j
cmwucGtpLmdvb2cvR1RTMU8xY29yZS5jcmwwggEFBgorBgEEAdZ5AgQCBIH2BIHz
APEAdwD2XJQv0XcwIhRUGAgwlFaO400TGTO/3wwvIAvMTvFk4wAAAXWyxYQuAAAE
AwBIMEYCIQCH6zkFy7ML4LOs6uXxQGdAY+ggd/MPz46av190Df4z0wIhALdmziRv
LtcrwcWa7apMJbfNVtRQiD0kRp9oQAx5+4t1AHYAlCC8Ho7VjWyIcx+CiyIsDdHa
TV5sT5Q9YdtOL1hNosIAAAF1ssWEfQAABAMARzBFAiEAiUjUL8/6cpQJ8p9tWUE5
Sib0yQLYp7Y2v+ocLCapxJACIHWcToQ7NTrnJW2uAqpyruoGppLPou6D4eugtC9/
8FmhMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAA4IBAQC2rVWLbSjwz3yIghOQGgHt0WPN8HjPbUoU
m6qqsrpqgIGg6ZpHRqO+Qym5yWTgabpCQ+5Mi/Q+FwJlqLd49UydB2xSndiuHPxj
aYanphIHLhx4NqFmNiktg+ZY7d5ARz0sVBkom2mc9WHnpPJQPWhXdBL0OgY7r+Ik
Y3NkRocsigeyyjHyE9VL6WTmRV64/ehih/pQCJBeb69yU0FkkWJ9EwwaN7Z0rSHd
4hdCTGfl1Lg34Nl5e6IoOTrOLh5uFHdJAiAdXWeDDLfYlgpUAhtf+pWYTWyKGhg0
2haxV9AoHZKY3KTd4tb6OC/O+6g0GauNoiOt55Os0pnKk5i0gZ0r
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
 1 s:/C=US/O=Google Trust Services/CN=GTS CA 1O1
   i:/OU=GlobalSign Root CA - R2/O=GlobalSign/CN=GlobalSign
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
---
Server certificate
subject=/C=US/ST=California/L=Mountain View/O=Google LLC/CN=www.google.com
issuer=/C=US/O=Google Trust Services/CN=GTS CA 1O1
---
No client certificate CA names sent
Server Temp Key: ECDH, X25519, 253 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 3208 bytes and written 281 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305
    Session-ID: BDC10F2FDB072D68E18A32B3BFE025D874AB08C97C11D2FA9D7105010CFE44A5
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 2A041A3C5386A91E9088D17502FE33DFE7794A688D205CCBFE5AEF86B1E6E3AD43580C28FD024BE8007F2A9CC9377B6D
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 100800 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    0000 - 01 bc 94 57 98 22 79 55-e5 74 07 e4 15 9d cb 21   ...W."yU.t.....!
    0010 - 31 6b e0 cb 69 f5 83 08-93 80 b1 88 fd 3e a9 3f   1k..i........>.?
    0020 - 22 c0 e3 1d f8 7b de 93-56 08 20 94 38 64 a3 58   "....{..V. .8d.X
    0030 - b2 a9 49 a4 20 9f 0f 14-b2 58 1d 47 ae ca de 9a   ..I. ....X.G....
    0040 - fe 72 0e 84 ad eb 14 8b-c3 2b fd 29 df da 8a 4c   .r.......+.)...L
    0050 - 53 21 1d 69 5c b6 5e 22-5a e7 ba c4 e0 65 7a b7   S!.i\.^"Z....ez.
    0060 - 39 d5 52 b4 19 40 16 72-eb 2e 88 03 8d 25 d7 0d   9.R..@.r.....%..
    0070 - 83 ac 13 9e ad 49 33 56-5c 74 e3 22 af af 69 d3   .....I3V\t."..i.
    0080 - fc 4b fe 40 57 44 94 e4-df 8c db 0f 9b 42 a7 1a   .K.@WD.......B..
    0090 - 4c 2d 1e c3 28 0d 41 78-ff b7 55 1c fb 02 59 b2   L-..(.Ax..U...Y.
    00a0 - 10 8f 44 b9 c2 4a ec 59-ef 6b 89 e0 15 b9 db 63   ..D..J.Y.k.....c
    00b0 - df 78 da 4e 0f 69 d7 c9-13 b5 0c 8f a4 67 65 17   .x.N.i.......ge.
    00c0 - f9 74 41 ae 6a da a5 22-b5 1c 7f 46 0d b0 64 74   .tA.j.."...F..dt
    00d0 - d8 40 f2 c0 46 e6 7c 71-d9 bf b8 91 75            .@..F.|q....u

    Start Time: 1608578092
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

Quick investigation reveals why this might be the case. `04:00:00:00:00:01:0F:86:26:E6:0D` is the serial number of the [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) cert chain root CA cert I can see when I inspect it in the browser:

```
openssl version -a                               
LibreSSL 2.8.3
built on: date not available
platform: information not available
options:  bn(64,64) rc4(16x,int) des(idx,cisc,16,int) blowfish(idx) 
compiler: information not available
OPENSSLDIR: "/private/etc/ssl"

ls -lR /private/etc/ssl                   
total 696
-rw-r--r--  1 irek  staff  346545 Dec 21 20:08 cert.pem
drwxr-xr-x  2 root  wheel      64 Sep  9  2019 certs
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     745 Sep  9  2019 openssl.cnf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    1006 Sep  9  2019 x509v3.cnf

/private/etc/ssl/certs:

cat /private/etc/ssl/cert.pem | grep -i '04:00:00:00:00:01:0F:86:26:E6:0D'
            04:00:00:00:00:01:0f:86:26:e6:0d
```

Up until now it could make sense. However, when I:

- delete this certificate from `/private/etc/ssl/cert.pem`,
- or specify CApath without this cert,
- or specify CAfile without this cert,
  nothing changes - the depth 2 root CA cert is not listed anyway.

I either made an incorrect assumption that I can get openssl to include top-level cert in cert chain with `-showcerts`, or I'm misinterpreting the role of `CApath` / `CAfile`, or I'm making a simple mistake somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I either made an incorrect assumption that I can get openssl to include top-level cert in cert chain with -showcerts,

Unfortunately the documentation in `man openssl` for LibreSSL is misleading (but not actually wrong):

> -showcerts
> Display the whole server certificate chain: normally only the
> server certificate itself is displayed.

Contrary to this here the relevant documentation of `man s_client` for OpenSSL 1.1.1 (same already in OpenSSL 1.0.2):

> -showcerts 
> Displays the server certificate list as sent by the server: **it only consists of certificates the server has sent** (in the order the
> server has sent them). **It is not a
> verified chain.**

This documentation is more clear and more correct. Looking at the source code inside LibreSSL (`apps/openssl/s_client.c`) one can see that the list of certificates is retrieved from `SSL_get_peer_cert_chain` which is documented as:

> SSL_get_peer_cert_chain() returns the peer chain **as sent by the peer**:
> it only consists of certificates the peer has sent (in the order the
> peer has sent them) and **it is not a verified chain**.

So, clearly these are only the certificates send by the server. Since the root of the trust chain must be local it is not included in this list.

As far as I can see the functionality you want is simply not available in the openssl tool.

Comment: All TLS specifications (2246, 4346, 5246, 8446) allow the server to omit the root cert from the Certificate message, and IME most servers do.